# TikZ Figure (Tree) how to stretch some branches so they align at bottom and move something horizontally?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to recreate an ugly tree into a nice TikZ figure tree. However the tree is a bit complex and I need help.

### However I am stuck with this 2 problems

1. I need to move something from level 3 "grandchild" down to level 6 "3 generations later grandchild" through prolonging the line.
2. I have some children in the middle that shall form something my figure calls "super tricky". It is basically between level 5 and 6 and a lot of children go into it. I made the lines red to draw your focus on that problem. It is basically closing loosed ends.(I mean this is obviously no family tree :D) The picture helps.

### This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=left}]]
  \node { I am fine with this}
    child { node {Top level \\ outside tree}}
    child { node {Top level \\ inside tree} 
      child { node {Level 1 \\ right}
             child { node {Level 2 \\ right }
             child {node { Lowest in  \\Left}}}}
      child { node {level 1 \\ middle}
            child { node {Level 2 \\ middle}
            child {node { lowest in  \\middle}}}}
      child { node {level 1 \\ right}       
        child { node {Level 2 \\ right left}
        child {node {Level 3 \\ right left}}} 
        child { node {Level 2 \\ right right} 
        child {node {Level 3 \\ right right}
        child{node{Level 4 \\ right left}}
       child{node{Level 4 \\ right right}
       child{node {Level 5 \\ right left}
       child{node{Lowest in \\right}}   }    } }}  }  }  ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ugly pic of what I want (not bout the design, I only care about the lines and nods]

Sorry for the ugly pic and thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this your final graph or just a part of it? Do you want to use the `tree` option or are other options also ok?

Comment: Final. So the "blue" picture is what I want to get as the final graph. But it's not at all about the design (colour/lines...), only about having the middle part "super tricky" with the associated lines and having the 3 "lowest" Childs aligned.  Preferable tree to recycle the code I already have but if much easier otherwise, ok.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried something using `tikz` with `nodes` and `calc`. I am not familar with `trees`, so this is my solution, maybe you will get some answer related to `trees`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=blue!75!black},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        %nodes
        
        %level 0
        
        \node at (0,0) (lv0a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=west] at ($(lv0a.east) + (4,0)$) (lv0b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        %level 1
        
        \node[anchor=north west] at ($(lv0b.south east) + (2,-1)$) (lv1a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv0b.south) + (0,-1) $) (lv1b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(lv0b.south west) + (-2,-1)$) (lv1c) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        %level 2
        
        \node[anchor=north west] at ($(lv1a.south) + (0.5,-1)$) (lv2a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(lv1a.south) + (-0.5,-1)$) (lv2b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv1b.south) + (0,-1)$) (lv2c) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv1c.south) + (0,-1)$) (lv2d) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        %level 3
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv2a.south) + (0,-1)$) (lv3a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv2b.south) + (0.5,-1)$) (lv3b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        % level 4
        
        \node[anchor=north west] at ($(lv3a.south) + (0.5,-1)$) (lv4a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(lv3a.south) + (-0.5,-1)$) (lv4b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        % level 5
        
        \node[anchor=north west] at ($(lv4a.south) + (0.5,-1)$) (lv5a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(lv4a.south) + (-0.5,-1)$) (lv5b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=east] at ($(lv5b.west) + (-5.5,0)$) (lv5c) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ super tricky}}};
        
        % level 6
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv5a.south) + (0.5,-1)$) (lv6a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=east] at ($(lv6a.west) + (-6.5,0)$) (lv6b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=east] at ($(lv6b.west) + (-2,0)$) (lv6c) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        %lines
        
        %level0
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (3,1.5) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv0a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (3,1.5) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv0b.north);
        
        %level1
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv0b.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv1a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv0b.south) -- (lv1b.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv0b.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv1c.north);
        
        %level2
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv1a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv2a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv1a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv2b.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv1b.south) -- (lv2c.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv1c.south) -- (lv2d.north);
        
        %level3
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv2a.south) --(lv3a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] ($(lv2b.south west) + (0.25,0)$) |- (lv3b.west);
        \draw[blue!75!black] ($(lv2c.south west) + (0.25,0)$) |- (lv6b.west);
        \draw[blue!75!black] ($(lv2d.south west) + (0.25,0)$) |- (lv6c.west);
        
        
        %level4
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv3a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv4a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv3a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv4b.north);
                
        %level5
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv4a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv5a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv4a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv5b.north);
        
        %super tricky
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.north) |- (lv3b.west);
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.north) |- (lv4b.west);
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.east) |- (lv5b.west);
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.east) -| (lv6b.north);
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.west) -| (lv6c.north);
        
        % level6    
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] ($(lv5a.south west) + (0.25,0)$) |- (lv6a.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case it suits your need and you need some adjustments, let me know in the comments.

**Edit**

Regarding your question: Does this suits your purpose?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!75!black},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        %nodes
        
        %start
        
        \node at (0,0) (start) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{start \\ position}}};
        
        %level 0
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(start.south) + (-2,-1) $) (lv0a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(start.south) + (2,-1)$) (lv0b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        %level 1
        
        \node[anchor=north west] at ($(lv0b.south east) + (2,-1)$) (lv1a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv0b.south) + (0,-1) $) (lv1b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
                
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(lv0b.south west) + (-2,-1)$) (lv1c) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        %level 2
        
        \node[anchor=north west] at ($(lv1a.south) + (0.5,-1)$) (lv2a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(lv1a.south) + (-0.5,-1)$) (lv2b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv1b.south) + (0,-1)$) (lv2c) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv1c.south) + (0,-1)$) (lv2d) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        %level 3
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv2a.south) + (0,-1)$) (lv3a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv2b.south) + (0,-1)$) (lv3b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        % level 4
        
        \node[anchor=north west] at ($(lv3a.south) + (0.5,-1)$) (lv4a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(lv3a.south) + (-0.5,-1)$) (lv4b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        % level 5
        
        \node[anchor=north west] at ($(lv4a.south) + (0.5,-1)$) (lv5a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(lv4a.south) + (-0.5,-1)$) (lv5b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=center] at (start.south |- lv5b) (lv5c) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ super tricky}}};
        
        % level 6
        
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(lv5a.south) + (0,-1)$) (lv6a) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=center] at (lv2c.south |- lv6a.west) (lv6b) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        \node[anchor=center] at (lv2d.south |- lv6a.west) (lv6c) {\textcolor{white}{\makecell[c]{Level \# \\ position}}};
        
        %lines
            
        %level0
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (start.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv0a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (start.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv0b.north);
        
        %level1
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv0b.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv1a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv0b.south) -- (lv1b.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv0b.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv1c.north);
        
        %level2
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv1a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv2a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv1a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv2b.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv1b.south) -- (lv2c.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv1c.south) -- (lv2d.north);
        
        %level3
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv2a.south) -- (lv3a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv2b.south) -- (lv3b.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv2c.south) -- (lv6b.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv2d.south) -- (lv6c.north);
        
        
        %level4
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv3a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv4a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv3a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv4b.north);
                
        %level5
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv4a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv5a.north);
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv4a.south) --++ (0,-0.5) -| (lv5b.north);
        
        %super tricky
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.north) |- (lv3b.west);
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.north) |- (lv4b.west);
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.east) |- (lv5b.west);
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.east) -| (lv6b.north);
        \draw[red!75!black] (lv5c.west) -| (lv6c.north);
        
        % level6    
        
        \draw[blue!75!black] (lv5a.south) -- (lv6a.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not familiar with that style - so it might take a while for me to understand it, but if it doesn't work with trees I will look at your excellent suggestion, thank you! (Do you think it would in this solution be easy to right align the boxes (not text) on the far left and the boxes with the red lines on the middle)?

Comment: There may be also a solution with `trees`, but I have not used it so far. Can you draw some lines in the scheme that I get you changing wishes? So what exactly you mean with the alignment changes.

Comment: I know it's been a year but this so much saved my ... that I just wanted to say, I used your method and like it a lot.